# API Instagram не работает получение историй

Tags: javascript, json, instagram

Не могу понять, почему не работает получение json ответа для историй для такой ссылки:https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/feed/user/1914321136/reel_media/ расковырял пару плагинов для хрома и лиса,у них такая ссылка, а меня кидает на авторизацию и все. Что не так?

Вот тут например все работает:https://github.com/CaliAlec/ChromeIGStory/blob/master/utils/InstagramApi.js

```
fetch("https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/feed/user/1914321136/reel_media/").then(function(e) {alert(e);console.log(e);     }).then(function(e) {var t = e.response.player_count;alert(t);}).catch(alert);
```

Comment: Никто не работал с сторисом инстаграма или за это хотят денюжку?

Comment: Мне может кто-нибудь помочь?!

Comment: Не работает апи инсты,поддержка у них молчит и тут нахер никто помочь не может суки